# Inconsistency with Running Macros Copy/Paste

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

When I exclusively run the Sub "EmailAbertura" (below) I get the desired result. However, when I run it within a list of other subs it copy and pastes a number that isn't even on the sheet. Why would that be occuring?  Thanks!

```
Sub EmailAbertura()
Dim Email As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim LCA As Workbook
Dim Lastro As Worksheet

Set Email = Workbooks("Email")
Set Sheet = Email.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set LCA = Workbooks("Controle de Lastro LCA_FEC - Test")
Set Lastro = LCA.Sheets("Controle Lastro")

Lastro.Range("B7").Copy
Sheet.Range("F2").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

But When I include it in this macro, it doesn't work.

```
Sub DoLCA() 'fazer todos de LCA para fechamento e abertura'
AddEmLCA
MenosResLCA
LCAHist
SalvarLCA
EmailDadosLCA
MudaDataLCA
DeleteDateLCA
EmailAbertura
SalvarLCA_aber
Fechar
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any errors? What do the other macros do? Did you try disabling some of the macros to identify which macro combination could be causing hte problem? Please clarify.

Comment: No errors. The other macros do a bunch of math to a lot of different cells. Range("B7") is a cell that has the summation of various cells. It only works when you isolate the individual macro itself.

Comment: Does the code reach the macro? Have you tried putting a breakpoint in there to see what happens?

Comment: As @MarekStejskal suggested, you should try stepping through your code to see where it is going wrong. Is it possible that `SalvarLCA_aber` or `Fechar` are replacing the contents of `Sheet.Range("F2")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that two (or more) macros are using Copy/Paste to perform their duties? Perhaps a second "Copy" is being performed before the corresponding "Paste" is executed. So, in other words, you did a second copy before you got to perform your first paste.